# Printing result after evaluation using conditional operator

Tags: c, conditional-operator

While executing the small piece of code below, every time I enter a character, the output is repeated and I don't understand why. Can someone explain to me why is it behaving like this?
ps: Just started my programming journey in c.

If I print a character such as 'a' I'm supposed to have 1 as output then another prompt asking me to enter a character again. But I instead get the 1, a prompt, and a 1 again then another prompt asking me to enter a character.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int usr_ch;
  for ( usr_ch = 0; (usr_ch != 'q');){
       printf("Enter a single character: (enter 'q' to stop)\n");
       usr_ch = getc(stdin);
       printf("%d\n", (usr_ch != 'q') ? 1 : 0));
  }
  return 0;
}
```

---

```
input: u
output:
Enter a single character: (enter 'q' to stop)
1
Enter a single character: (enter 'q' to stop)
1
Enter a single character: (enter 'q' to stop)
```

Comment: Enter is also a character. If you type a and then press enter, these are two characters.

Comment: For line-based user input, I suggest that you always read an entire line at once, by using the function [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a great answer explaining the additional `'\n'` character generated when the user presses <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. Continuing from the comments below the question and comment by [@AllanWard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9706/allan-wind) about the use of `fgets()`, it can provide the ability to take all single characters as input and end the input when <kbd>ENTER</kbd> alone is pressed. There are a number of other benefits as well.

When reading a line with `fgets()` you read the input into a buffer (character array or allocated block of memory). *Don't skimp on buffer size...* `fgets()` reads and includes the trailing `'\n'` in the buffer it fills. This means an entire line of input is consumed, including the trailing `'\n'` given a sufficiently sized buffer. The `'\n'` is not left in the input buffer (`stdin`) unread. This will avoid the problem you are experiencing.

To access the first character in the array, all you need do is derefernce the pointer. (an array is converted to a pointer to its first element on access, [C18 Standard - 6.3.2.1(p3)](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2596.pdf#subsection.6.3.2)). So if you declare `char line[1024];` to hold the input, simply referencing `*line` provides access to the first character.

Using `fgets()` avoids all of the pitfalls new C programmers fall into using `scanf()` and eliminates the `'\n'` being left unread. These are the primary reasons new C programmers (as well as not so new C programmers) are encouraged to take all user input using `fgets()` (or POSIX `getline()` which behaves in the same manner, but can also provide auto-allocation to handle a string of any length)

In addition to taking the input, without much more effort you can ensure the user has only entered one-printable character with a few simple tests. This allows you to handle individual error cases as needed. A short example of the use of `fgets()` and handling several of the foreseeable error cases can be written as:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXC 1024     /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main (void)
{
  char line[MAXC];    /* buffer to hold line */
  
  /* prompt and then read input into line */
  while (fputs ("Enter a single character: (enter alone to stop): ", stdout) &&
         fgets (line, MAXC, stdin)) {
    /* if ENTER alone, break */
    if (*line == '\n') {
      puts ("exiting");
      break;
    }
    /* if not a single-character, handle error */
    else if (line[1] != '\n') {
      fputs ("  error: more than 1 char entered.\n", stderr);
    }
    /* if printable character, output */
    else if (isprint ((unsigned char)*line)) {
      printf ("  you entered '%c'\n", *line);
    }
    else {  /* otherwise, handle error */
      fputs (" error: non-printable character generated.\n", stderr);
    }
  }
}
```

(**note:** these are only a few examples of the classification test you can use. You are free to add or remove as many as you like. You can even provide a lookup-table for non-printable character and output a representation, e.g. `'\t'`, when one is pressed, it's entirely up to you.)

**Example Use/Output**

The following exercises each of the covered error cases (the `'\t'` character is used for the non-printable character), e.g.

```
$ ./bin/fgets-char
Enter a single character: (enter alone to stop): a
  you entered 'a'
Enter a single character: (enter alone to stop): b
  you entered 'b'
Enter a single character: (enter alone to stop): q
  you entered 'q'
Enter a single character: (enter alone to stop): Q
  you entered 'Q'
Enter a single character: (enter alone to stop):
 error: non-printable character generated.
Enter a single character: (enter alone to stop): foo
  error: more than 1 char entered.
Enter a single character: (enter alone to stop):
exiting
```

There is absolutely nothing wrong with using `getc()` or `fgetc()` or `getchar()` for taking a single-character as input, but you must handle any additional characters that remain unread (including the trailing `'\n'`). Then what if the user presses <kbd>ENTER</kbd> twice in a row, or a cat steps on the keyboard generating 500 keypresses? That's where `fgets()` can help.

Another approach, unfortunately non-portable between different OS's, is to place the terminal in raw unbuffered (non-cannonical) mode where the input is processed immediately. For Linux you can use `tcsetattr()`. (you can also use `setvbuf`, see [man 3 setbuf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setbuf.3.html) to switch between unbuffered, line-buffered or fully-buffered input) For Windows `getch()` can be used.

Worth exploring each as you continue your learning in C. Let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 1):

stdin, by default, is line oriented when you enter "u\n" so `getc()` will first return `u` and in the next call `\n`.

In this case it is more natural to use a `do`-`while`-loop (or a `for(;;)` with a break at the end of the loop body).  Then read a letter in a loop till you find one you like (i.e. not a `\n`).   It's a good idea to handle EOF.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int usr_ch;
    do {
        printf("Enter a single character: (enter 'q' to stop)\n");
        while((usr_ch = getc(stdin)) && usr_ch == '\n');
        printf("%d\n", usr_ch != 'q'));
    } while(usr_ch != 'q' && usr_ch != EOF);
}
```

and here is example runs:

```
Enter a single character: (enter 'q' to stop)
a
1
Enter a single character: (enter 'q' to stop)
q
0
```

AYou can also just `fgets()` a line or use `scanf(" %c", &usr_ch)` to ignore leading white space.